# Floyd Warshall algorithm implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, floyd-warshall

I've written code for a 100 x 100 adjacency matrix that represents the following directed graph:

[image: Corner Store Graph]

I'm attempting to use a Floyd-Warshall algorithm to find the shortest path for all pairs of blue nodes in the graph. How do you only find the all pairs shortest path for the selected nodes? Here's the code I've written thus far:

```js
public class AdjacencyMatrix
{       
    public static final int NUM_NODES = 100;
    public static final int INF = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    
    public static boolean even(int num) 
    {
        return num%2==0;
    }

    public static boolean odd(int num) 
    {
        return num%2==1;
    }

    public static void initialize(int [][] adjMat, int N) 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j <N; j++)
                adjMat[i][j]=INF;

        for(int x = 0; x<N; x++)
        {
            int row = x/10;
            int column = x%10;

            if (even(row)) {
                if (column!=9)
                    adjMat[x][x+1]=1;
            }
            if (odd(row)) {
                if (column!=0)
                    adjMat[x][x-1]=1;
            }
            if (even(column)){
                if (row!=9)
                    adjMat[x][x+10]=1;
            }
            if (odd(column)) {
                if (row!=0)
                    adjMat[x][x-10]=1;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void floydWarshall(int[][] adjMat, int N)
    {
     adjMat = new int[N][N];
     initialize(adjMat, NUM_NODES);

        for(int k = 0; k < N; ++k) {
           for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
              for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
                 adjMat[i][j] = Math.min(adjMat[i][j], adjMat[i][k] +   adjMat[k][j]);
    }
}
}

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int adjMat[][] = new int[NUM_NODES][NUM_NODES];
        initialize(adjMat, NUM_NODES);
        
        int A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,W;
        
        A = 20;
        B = 18;
        C = 47;
        D = 44;
        E = 53;
        F = 67;
        G = 95;
        H = 93;
        I = 88;
        W = 66;
       
        System.out.println(adjMat[A][B]);

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you undid anything.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should not assign new value to adjMat parameter in floydWarshall(), because the value will not be saved after exiting the method.

The next step is to check adjMat[i][k] and adjMat[k][j] for equality to INF and continue the loop if so:

```
for(int k = 0; k < N; ++k) {
   for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
      for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
        if (adjMat[i][k] != INF && adjMat[k][j] != INF) {
            adjMat[i][j] = Math.min(adjMat[i][j], adjMat[i][k] + adjMat[k][j]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest Floyd-Warshall algo implemenation:

```
for(int k = 0; k < N; ++k) {
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
            adjMat[i][j] = Math.min(adjMat[i][j], adjMat[i][k] + adjMat[k][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

After running this piece of cade `adjMat` will contain shortest distances between every pair of nodes.

Update: to avoid integer overflow, fill the matrix with `Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2`. In general case, it's dangerous to set the maximum possible value to variable as infinity, because you can't perform addition operation with it.

Comment: I've added your code to the floydWarshall() method, but it's ouputting a matrix of all 0's.

Comment: I'm still not getting this code to output properly. It looks like the logic is correct, so I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: I am not familiar with java, but will adjMat[i][k] + adjMat[k][j] overflow if one term is Intmax?

Comment: you must remember you have to clean the matrix first. The first step is to set all matrix' values to infinite (very big value), and then, set all diagonal values to 0. This should do the job: `for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) M[i][j] = (i == j? 0 : 99999999);`, then you run the FW algorithm just as described above.

Comment: Not really, I'm working with matrix that represents a graph.